# range function in sml with a step parameter

Tags: sml

I am very new to SML and functional programming.

I have searched the site but was unable to find an answer to my question.

I am trying to write a basic range function with a start, stop, and step parameter.

For example, range(2, 12, 3) should return the list [2,5,8,11].

I don't get any errors, but when I try running range(2,12,3); the cursor advances to the next line and nothing happens, I can't even type anything into the smlnj app.

Here is my code:

```
fun range(start, stop, step) =
if start = stop then nil
else start::range(start+step, stop, step);
```

Which outputs this:

```
val range = fn : int * int * int -> int list
```

What changes do I need to make to my code so that when I run range(2,12,3) I get [2,5,8,11] ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your condition (`start = stop`) to break the recursion is wrong.  In your example you'll perform recursive calls with `start=2`, `start=5`, `start=8`, `start=11`, `start=14`, ...  leading to an infinite loop.  It's not that nothing happens, it's just that smnlj keeps computing...

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite recursion whenever `stop - start` is not a multiple of the step size (or zero).

Look at `range(11,12,3)`, which should generate your last number:

```
if 11 = 12 then nil
else 11::range(11+3, 12, 3)
```

This will calculate `range(14,12,3)`:

```
if 14 = 12 then nil
else 14::range(14+3, 12, 3)
```

and then `range(17,12,3)`, and so on, ad infinitum.

You need to replace `=` with either `>` or `>=`, depending on whether `stop` should be included or not.